# Converting currency symbols '$' '£' to html code &dollar; &pound;?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I stored the symbols in a table in a database, e.g.

```
country | currency_code | currency_symbol | currency_rate
UK        GBP             £                 1.0000
EU        EUR             €                 1.XXXX
USA       USD             $                 1.XXXX
Canada    CAD             $                 1.XXXX
```

The problem is that the currency symbols are not valid in html so they show up as `�` instead.

Do I need to add another column to my table for HTML codes e.g. `&pound;` `&euro;` `&dollar;` or is there a simple function in PHP that I can use to wrap around the character to convert it to HTML?

Comment: @mgraph no I guess thats the one?

Comment: Have you tried just storing the HTML values instead of the symbol? They should convert in your output to the symbol on display then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currency symbols are perfectly "HTML safe". What you have is an *encoding problem*. You are outputting these characters encoded in one encoding (likely Latin-1), but your browser is interpreting them in some other encoding (likely UTF-8). The actual encoding and the declared encoding need to match. Follow [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) to see where your problem is.

Comment: interesting link & thanks for helping me to understand the problem